# How to append different timestamp dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to append my dataframes which are two different timestamps.

The first one is

```
d1
0   2000-01-05 00:00:00+00:00
1   2000-01-06 00:00:00+00:00
2   2000-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
3   2000-01-10 00:00:00+00:00
4   2000-01-11 00:00:00+00:00
```

and the second one is

```
d2
1   2000-01-06 00:00:00+00:00
2   2000-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
3   2000-01-10 00:00:00+00:00
4   2000-01-11 00:00:00+00:00
5   2000-01-12 00:00:00+00:00
```

however the result of `pd.concat([d1, d2], axis = 1)` is

```
d1  d2
0   2000-01-05 00:00:00+00:00   NaT
1   2000-01-06 00:00:00+00:00   2000-01-06 00:00:00+00:00
2   2000-01-07 00:00:00+00:00   2000-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
3   2000-01-10 00:00:00+00:00   2000-01-10 00:00:00+00:00
4   2000-01-11 00:00:00+00:00   2000-01-11 00:00:00+00:00
```

How to append those 2 dataframes without NaT?

Comment: One `df` has 4 rows and the other has 5 What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Extending them so there are 9 rows? Or combine them as seperate columns? Please show expected output!

Answer (score 1):

pandas will append the dataframe based on the index, if you want to append without the index you may want to use:

```
pd.concat([d1, d2], axis = 1,ignore_index=True)
```

On the other hand, if you like how it is appended but you want to filter the NaT data you can use

```
pd.concat([d1, d2], axis = 1).dropna()
```